# Работа с папками в C++/CLI

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Добрый день,

такая ситуация, нужно положить файл по определённому пути, но есть возможность, что определённых каталогов (папок) попросту не существует, тогда логично что нужно их создать. Вопрос : как проверить существование всех каталогов пути, если не существуют, то создать самостоятельно?

Пример: положить по пути

> D:\some\new\directory\

папка some пуста, т.е. необходимо создать директорию

> D:\some\new\

а затем

> D:\some\new\directory\

Comment: Уточните средства разработки

Comment: Что именно вы имеете в виду?

Comment: В смысле VisualStudio  с CLR, голый C++, Qt

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa363855(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Visual Studio c CLR

Comment: можно winAPI прикрутить раз под винду 
 

bool DirectoryExists

Comment: @Akuma925: Зачем так сложно?

Comment: а в чем сложность???

Comment: @VladD можно вообще было использовать dirent и errno для пущей переносимости.

Comment: @Akuma925: Прикручивать WinAPI через P/Invoke само по себе не подарок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [`Directory::CreateDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1):

```
Directory::CreateDirectory("D:\\some\\new\\directory\\");
```

Промежуточные каталоги создадутся при необходимости автоматически.

Comment: А если данный каталог существует, то ничего не произойдёт?

Comment: @koshachok: Не-а, ничего не произойдёт. Документация пишет: «Creates all directories and subdirectories in the specified path **unless they already exist**.»